# Antivirus deleting files?

Tags: anti-virus, ccleaner, avira, gis

I am working with QGIS and noticed recently that some files (.shx) disappeared...
I read somewhere on StackExchange that an antivirus may "clean" some folders (I have Avira and CCleaner). Is it possible that one of them deleted these files? 
How can I avoid that this happens again next time?

Comment: Well, an antivirus' job is to delete harmful files... However .shx (ArcGIS files) shouldn't be harmful... I am not proficient with that but couldn't QGIS or yourself have deleted those files?

Comment: OK but then.... how could this happen? I mean, I am sure I didn't delete them myself, especially because it happened a few times, always with these shx files...

Comment: In my line of work I move around several .dwg (AutoCAD files) and also several structural analysis files into several folders. Although I have some care to not delete files, I do delete several temporary files resultant from processing the files. My advice in diagnosing the problem is the following: 1. Backup every important thing. 2. Do what you do usually, but keep a record of what you do. 3. When you notice the files missing, just trace back until you found the reason. I doubt it is the antivirus' fault but you can try to disable them temporarily.

Comment: **1)** Check the Avira log. CCleaner won't delete such files, it only cleans out the %TEMP% folder for example. **2)** If indeed, it was Avira, use some better product.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Doktoro: I back up regularly but the shx files were deleted from the back up folders too... I guess I should save them on an external hard disk. Shiki: I checked but found nothing...